# cygwin/X version 1.17 xinit version 1.3.* breaks run.exe

Tags: cygwin, x11, xterm

i have been using cygwin/X for many years and have not had any major problems, until the upgrade of xinit to version 1.3.x, it breaks everything without any warning at all. people wonder why open source gets such a bad reputation, it's this kind of blindsiding that does it...
anyway, prior to xinit 1.3.x i started Xwin via the Xwin icon. i could then start xterm (or emacs or any X application) using run.exe which i would pin to the taskbar. my command line is as such:

D:\cygwin\bin\run.exe -p /bin bash ~/scripts/xterm.sh

my xterm.sh is as follows:

export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0
xterm &
exit

this has worked like a charm for YEARS, now it doesn't do anything.

even doing this in a windows cmd:

set DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0

d:\cygwin\bin\run.exe -p /usr/X11R6/bin xterm

doesn't work anymore...

does anyone know how to start an Xwin application (xterm, emacs ...) via the dos command line ...

Answer (score 1):

Try to set DISPLAY to `:0.0` (not 127.0.0.1:0.0). [Source](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2015-03/msg00240.html).